# Column Order in Pandas Dataframe from dict of dict

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a pandas dataframe from a dictionary of dict in the following way :

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stats).transpose()
```

I want the columns in a particular order but cant seem to figure out how to do so. I have tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['c1','c2','c3']).from_dict(stats).transpose()
```

but the final output is always `c3, c2, c1`. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stats).transpose().loc[:, ['c1','c2','c3']]
```

or just

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(stats).transpose()[['c1','c2','c3']]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the order, you can manually adjust as follows:

```
df = df[['c1','c3','c2']]
```

You can also do it by just creating a list of column names

```
disiredOrder = ['c1','c3','c2']
df = df[disiredOrder]
```